# Solve a system of nonlinear differential equation.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am doing some exercises from applied math, but it boils down to solving the following system of nonlinear differential equation:

$$\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
 8A'(\tau)=-3A^{3}(\tau)-3A(\tau)B^{2}(\tau)=-3A(\tau)(A^{2}(\tau)+B^{2}(\tau))\\
 8B'(\tau)=-3A^{2}(\tau)B(\tau)-3B^{3}(\tau)=-3B(\tau)(A^{2}(\tau)+B^{2}(\tau)),
 \end{array}
\right.$$
with initial conditions $A(0)=0$ and $B(0)=1$.

I am not sure if there is a general formula for such system, so I just tried to play with them to see if there any beautiful relation.

Firstly I found that $$A'(\tau)B(\tau)=B'(\tau)A(\tau)\implies A'(\tau)B(\tau)-B'(\tau)A(\tau)=0,$$ but this does not help me since it does not necessarily form a product rule.

Then, I actually expect $A(\tau)$ and $B(\tau)$ are of some forms of $\cos(a\tau)$ and $\sin(a\tau)$, since if so then $A^{2}(\tau)+B^{2}(\tau)=1$, and we have $$A'(\tau)=-\frac{3}{8}A(\tau)\ \ \text{and}\ \ B'(\tau)=-\frac{3}{8}B(\tau), $$ but then I got suck again since if, say, $A(\tau)=\cos(a\tau)$, then $A'(\tau)=-\frac{3}{8}A(\tau)$ gives us $$-a\sin(a\tau)=-\frac{3}{8}\cos(a\tau)\implies \frac{3}{8}\cos(a\tau)-a\sin(a\tau)=0.$$ We can indeed play with trig identity $\sin(x-y)=\sin(x)\cos(y)-\cos(x)\sin(y)$ here, so we have $$\sin(x-a\tau)=0,$$ where $x$ is such that $\sin(x)=\frac{3}{8}$ and $\cos(x)=a$. Then what I should do? I am kind of confusing myself.

Thanks!

**Edit 1:**

Wolframalpha gives me the general solution $$A(\tau)=-\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3c_{1}^{2}\tau-8c_{2}+3\tau}}\ \ \text{and}\ \ B(\tau)=-\dfrac{2c_{1}}{\sqrt{3c_{1}^{2}\tau-8c_{2}+3\tau}},$$ but this contradicts the initial condition. In this form $A(0)$ cannot be $0$. This seems suggest that $A(\tau)=0$ for all $\tau$, but I am not sure how to show it.

Comment: What about $\displaystyle A\equiv0, B=\frac2{\sqrt{3\tau+4}}$?

Comment: @ProfessorVector it works! but I am not sure how to prove it

Comment: @ProfessorVector for example, we argue by contradiction that A must be identically $0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you were almost there:
$$A'(\tau)B(\tau)=B'(\tau)A(\tau)\implies A'(\tau)B(\tau)-B'(\tau)A(\tau)=0,$$ and not the product rule, but the quotient rule is relevant, now:
$$\frac{d}{d\tau}\,\frac{A(\tau)}{B(\tau)}=\frac{A'(\tau)B(\tau)-B'(\tau)A(\tau)}{B(\tau)^2}=0.\tag{quotient}$$ So $\displaystyle\frac{A(\tau)}{B(\tau)}$ must be a constant, i.e. $0$ because of the initial condition (but also a constant, $1/c_1$, in the general solution given by Wolfram Alpha, as you will notice). From that, you have $A\equiv0$, and you get a simple differential equation for $B$ with the solution $$B(\tau)=\frac2{\sqrt{3\tau+4}}.$$
Remark: $B(0)=1$ means that $B(\tau)>0$ in some neighborhood of $0$, and (quotient) is valid for all $\tau$ where $B(\tau)\neq0$. The resulting differential equation for $B$ guarantees that it stays away from $0$.

Comment: Nice. thank you so much!